# Missing line break on election results

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election-page

OK so this has been annoying me for *years* so I figured it's time to put an official meta post about it.

When viewing an election results page (e.g. on [Server Fault)](https://serverfault.com/election), the descriptive text is inline with the winners flair boxes, which means that it word wraps and doesn't look very nice.

[image]

The two that are highligted do not have a `<br>` on them, but the first and last election do.

Comment: Looks fine on SO and gaming (and others I checked), so it's depedant on the per-site design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue specific to the SF election page (or rather those two elections).

I've added the missing `<br>` tag and all is well with the page now.

Comment: Nope. Happens in many sites. [travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/election), [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/election), [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/election) and probably many more. Something in the basic CSS is wrong. (or there is missing `<br />` in all of them)

Comment: Probably missing `<br />`s... this is quite... manual.

Comment: Weird. Can you at least make sure it won't happen in the future for new sites?

Comment: It depends on the person who populates the election results. One day... one day...

Comment: So, [tag:status-SEP]? (liked more the Hebrew translation actually, בשמ"א ;))

Comment: Heh. More that the current way the page works is a bit of an old hack, and we need to spend some time fixing it for good, one of these days...

Comment: Oh no... the worst possible ETA. ;D

Comment: Technical Debt FTW